# 1980s/90s cartoon about infected people with powers hiding in a fog?

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I'm looking for the name of a cartoon, but I only remember bits and pieces of it. In it half the planet (Earth?) is taken over by some sort of virus. The virus maintains geographic control of its infected with some sort of fog that is impenetrable or something.

The infected think it's wonderful, but of course the healthy people want to cure them or hold them at bay or something.

I know this was a thing; I just can't for the life of me remember what it was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Spiral Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_Zone)?

[image: Spiral Zone]

**Plot Summary:**

Large parts of the world are engulfed in a mist that turns people into brainless slaves that obey evil mastermind Overlord. These areas are known as the Spiral Zone. Fighting to free the planet from Overlord and his minions is an international team of soldiers known as the Zone Riders.

[Here is the opening on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wO2Cd9tyUvY).